# Convert an image into an url button in Google Sheets Using Apps Script

Tags: image, url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

Peace Be Upon You,

I need some help with google app scripts.

**What I want to do:**

1. I want to add an image in google sheets
2. Add an app script to this image
3. Configure the script so that when I click the image it takes me to a url (external or internal)

**What Help I need:**
I'm a beginner and would like to get the work done.
Please help me with a sample or template code to place the url.

**Why app script for this simple task:**
Google sheets kept no other way to point a drawing or image to a url. I've tried everything.

I’m new here. Please forgive me if asking this way is against manners. But please help me.

Thanks,

Md. Iftikhar Alam Omar

https://iftikharomar.co

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Insert the image.
Step 2: Create the following in the script.

```
function btnClick() {
  var html = "<script>window.open('https://google.com');google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html); 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Loading...');
}
```

Step 3: Right-click on the image, then hit the 3 dots in the upper right-hand corner. Click assign script and type `btnClick` in the box.

See this [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hpiTnTTuKo0mBS8VmTYt8xOGx82WJjPXQqlgkvqTHp4/edit?usp=sharing) for a functional example.